# How to render a binary with play 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am stuck on an obvious one:

How to render an image from a controller using Play 2.0 ?

With play 1.0 there was a `renderBinary()` method. It is now gone.

Play-RC1 only defined 3 content types: Txt, Html and Xml....

Therefore, *how to serve a binary from the controller?*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Scala with Play 2.x, instead of `renderBinary()` or `Binary()` juste use

```
Ok(byteArray).as(mimeType)
```

In the previous example, this gives:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    val app = Play.application
    var file = Play.application.getFile("pics/pic.jpg")
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file)(scala.io.Codec.ISO8859)
    val byteArray = source.map(_.toByte).toArray
    source.close()

    Ok(byteArray).as("image/jpeg")
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, though I would advise moving the actual file access to the model.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Scala solution:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    val app = Play.application
    var file = Play.application.getFile("pics/pic.jpg")
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file)(scala.io.Codec.ISO8859)
    val byteArray = source.map(_.toByte).toArray
    source.close()

    Binary(byteArray, None, "image/jpeg");
  }
}
```

`Binary` is a method of `Controller`, just like `Ok`. The source code in `Results.scala` suggests it will be deleted:

```
/** To be deleted... */
def Binary(data: Array[Byte], length: Option[Long] = None, contentType: String = "application/octet-stream") = {

  val e = Enumerator(data)

  SimpleResult[Array[Byte]](header = ResponseHeader(
    OK,
    Map(CONTENT_TYPE -> contentType) ++ length.map(length =>
      Map(CONTENT_LENGTH -> (length.toString))).getOrElse(Map.empty)),
    body = e)

}
```

But there is no suggestion of what to use instead. I suppose one could simply create one's own object to do this if required.

Comment: thank you. I should have clarified... what about a Java version ?

Answer (score 6):

In Java, as per latest Play 2.0 code, *Results* class contains a method [status](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Results.java#L91) which can receive a *byte[]* as parameter, which should be of use for your scenario.