# How to show images in play framework 2.1

Tags: java, playframework

```
public static void getImage(String fileName) {
        File file = new File( "~/" + fileName );
        response.contentType = "image/png";
        renderBinary( file );
    }
```

In this method response and renderBinary are showing errors

Comment: This is not working properly in play framework 2.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305853/how-to-render-a-binary-with-play-2-0

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are using is for Playframework 1.x, and it is not compatible with the 2.x version. These two versions are totally different.

As @rags mentioned, take a look at [How to render a binary with play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305853/how-to-render-a-binary-with-play-2-0)

More explanations on Content-Type are available here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaResponse

Answer (score 1):

public static Result getImage() throws IOException {
        File file = new File( "d:\Images\"+name+".jpg" );

```
    return ok(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)).as("image/jpeg");
}
```

Here I am using IOException because I am using file operations, this is another way used rather than renderBinary