# How to serve static asset from a controller action in Play Framework 2.3?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

In my application I need to serve a static file from public folder. And for some reasons I have to do it from Java controller action.

The first solution that came to my mind is to do something like:

```
public class Central extends Controller {
     public static Result index() {
         return Assets.at("/public", "central/index.html", false);
     }
}
```

But `Assets.at` method return type is  `play.api.mvc.Action<play.api.mvc.AnyContent>`

Is there some way to transform it to type  `play.mvc.Result` ?

Or any other elegant way to do serve static file from Java controller action ?

Comment: I found this answer for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305853/how-to-render-a-binary-with-play-2-0

Comment: Why do you want result instead of action? Result can't be used outside action.

Comment: I can and I guess I should return Result from my index() action. But I have no idea what use of play.api.mvc.Action can I make.

Answer (score 4):

change your method return type.
like this:

```
public class Central extends Controller {
     public static play.api.mvc.Action<play.api.mvc.AnyContent> index() {
         return Assets.at("/public", "central/index.html", false);
     }
}
```